# add a new empty line in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to add a new empty line in ui-grid. I've tried looking in different tuto and example, but all that I found didn't reply to my spec, and I wasn't able to adapt it to what I'm looking for.
In fact I'm looking how to add a new empty line in an existing ui-grid neither using a button outside the grid nor a button in the rowfooter.
I'm looking to add a abutton in the grid like the + button shown in the screen shot below 
[image]

or may be render automatically a new empty line when the rendering the ui-grid and a new one when all rows were filled.
I tried doing that using function in cell template but it's not working.
any help is really appreciated

Comment: Can you add some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option sounds like more of a CSS issue to me. Essentially, the add button would use some sort of font library containing a +, and you would need to position it in the corner of the grid. Perhaps looking at the grid footer would be a starting place. It sounds like you've seen the basics of creating an add row button here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/112_swapping_data

The second option (*render automatically a new empty line when the rendering the ui-grid and a new one when all rows were filled*) requires a JavaScript approach.

The basic logic I followed is:

1. (Assume) Some data loads from somewhere in a backend (in this sample, it's a simulated load returning a promise as $http or $resource would).
2. After that data is loaded, we append a new row. We wait for the data first; otherwise we'd not be pushing the new row to the correct location.
3. Upon completion of the edit action, we set a timeout to ensure subsequent edits on other cells do not keep firing a new row. If the timeout is reached, we append a new row. If a subsequent edit action occurs, and a timeout promise exists (for adding a new row), we cancel it. Once no edit actions occur, and the timeout is reached, we push the new row.

To ensure that we are only taking action when our "extra row" is modified, when we create a row, a reference is maintained to the current row such that we can evaluate whether or not a received event is of interest (var newRowTimeoutPromise).

The core logic in code is below, with a sample implementation in Plnkr:

```
var extraRow = null,
        addNewTimeoutMillis = 2000,
        newRowTimeoutPromise = null;

    loadData().then(function(data) {
        $scope.gridOpts.data = data;
    }).finally(function() {
        // add initial empty row, and set our reference to it
        extraRow = addEmptyRow($scope.gridOpts.data);
    })

    $scope.gridOpts = {
        showGridFooter: true,
        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

            // listen for cell edit completion
            gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {

                // test if the edited row was the "extra row"
                // otherwise, and edit to any row would fire a new row

                // Set a timeout so we don't create a new row if the user has
                // not finished their edit(s) on other fields
                newRowTimeoutPromise = $timeout(function() {
                    if (rowEntity == extraRow) {
                        // add a new empty row, and set our reference to it
                        extraRow = addEmptyRow($scope.gridOpts.data);
                        newRowTimeoutPromise = null;
                    }
                }, addNewTimeoutMillis);
            })

            // Listen for cell edit start, and cancel if we have a pending new
            // row add. Otherwise, each time you finish the edit on a cell,
            // this will fire.
            gridApi.edit.on.beginCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newRowTimeoutPromise != null) {
                  $timeout.cancel(newRowTimeoutPromise);
                }
            })

        }
    };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/IMisQEHlaZDCmCSpmnMZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery to fetch and change style of specific cell elements of the cell template.

Here is a helpful [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unqanv22/)

Here is the controller script : -

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
function($scope) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {};

    $scope.Add = function() {

       $scope.gridOptions.data.push( { firstName: ' ',lastName:'',company:'' });
$(".ui-grid-coluiGrid").prevObject["0"].activeElement.style.display="none";  
$(".ui-grid-cell")[$scope.gridOptions.data.length-2].style.display="inline";
  };
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = registerGridApi;
function registerGridApi(gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi= gridApi

};   

 $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
        name: 'firstName',
        field: 'firstName', 
    }, {
        name: 'lastNamer',
        field: 'firstName'
    }, {
        name: 'ShowScope',
        cellTemplate: '<button id="btb" ng-click="grid.appScope.Add()">+</button>'
    }];
     $scope.gridOptions.data = [{ yourdata}];
}
 ]);
```

To make it work properly 2 more things have to be done

1. Use cellContentEditable to make the rows editable
2. In order to disable display style of cell template button that appears on cells corresponding to rows of already existing data,you could use angular foreach or a for loop to iterate through these rows and disable style(I tried using renderContainers but it always returns the length of rendered rows outside Add functions as 0).

Answer (score 0):

I have a working plunker over here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Vnn4K5DcCdiercc22Vry?p=preview

In columnDefs, I have defined a separate column for add:

```
{
   name: 'add',
   displayName: '',
   enableCellEdit: false,
   enableColumnMenu: false,
   width: '3%',
   cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-click="grid.appScope.addRow()"><span  ng-click="grid.appScope.addRow()">Add</span></div>'
  }
```

And

```
$scope.addRow= function(){
   var newlist = {"remarks":'',"testName":''};
   $scope.gridOptions.data.push(newlist);
}
```

Update: A second plunker with bootstrap icons for add/remove
http://plnkr.co/edit/FjsA2r?p=preview